# re split to break a string into components but keeping separators

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to break a string into components

```
s = 'Hello [foo] world!'
re.split(r'\[(.*?)\]', s)
```

which gives me

```
['Hello ', 'foo', ' world!']
```

But I want to achieve

```
['Hello ', '[foo]', ' world!']
```

Please help!

Comment: Capture the brackets, `r'(\[.*?])'`

Comment: Why not just `s.split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s = 'Hello [foo] world!'
print(re.split(r'(\[[^][]*])', s))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgDADA3VfUCTDGxdndP9Q6iZGk0qaQGF@P3nT61kvy3Fq6VayCxa7AAm6NzAJ4ihA8Ynz0rlNLuXqLU1FOf5zfEHdCGii4EUoIrX0).

**Results**: `['Hello ', '[foo]', ' world!']`

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: This is good but any work around on this if the input is "[hello] [world]" then it comes ['', '[hello]', ' ','[world]', '']. Two empty strings are coming at begining and ending.

Comment: @DaveB Not a problem, use `[x for x in re.split(r'(\[[^][]*])', s) if x.strip()]`

Comment: Tip for formatting the regex breakdown: If you remove the `--------------` and place the commentary behind `#` on each line, the entire block can be copied as-is into a regex with the `X` flag set. That's both more compact and more practical.